# How to set max length of datagridview column

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` where the units can be entered in a `TextBox` column.

How do I restrict the *input length* of this column to `6` characters?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the [`MaxInputLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewtextboxcolumn.maxinputlength.aspx) property of the `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`.

This property is available through the Designer or through code:

```
((DataGridViewTextBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[yourColumn]).MaxInputLength = 6;
```

Comment: Thanks; used your suggestion and works great! -> `private void dgAPB_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {((DataGridViewTextBoxColumn)dgAPB.Columns[1] = 6;}`

Answer (score 6):

Please use [CellValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx) event of *DataGridView*.

In the handler of the event you can check [ColumnIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.columnindex.aspx) and [RowIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.rowindex.aspx) properties of [DataGridViewCellEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fwkafb0.aspx) argument to identify that grid's field of interest is edited and then - take appropriate actions.

As stated in other answers - most natural way to restrict text lengths for *DataGridView* field is to modify respective grid column properties. Properties of grid columns can be altered on *Edit Columns* form that is invoked for grid control in *form designer* with right click menu item *Edit Columns...*:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may have to play with cell-edit events.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have the columns ready to manipulate if you're using data binding. For data binding, using the **ColumnAdded** listener can help:

```
public FormSingleValidation(BindingList<ValidateSingle> validateSingles)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dataGridViewSingleValidation.ColumnAdded += ColumnAdded;

    this.validateSingles = validateSingles;
    var source = new BindingSource(validateSingles, null);
    dataGridViewSingleValidation.DataSource = source;
}

private void ColumnAdded(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Column.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewTextBoxColumn))
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column = (DataGridViewTextBoxColumn) e.Column;
        column.MaxInputLength = 6;
    }
}
```

Caveats

1. Obviously this applies to all text columns without discrimination, you can add a conditional filter using the column's name if you only want specific columns to be effected.