# Why Excel Data not displayed complete in DataGrid in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm developing my app in VB.Net with the source below but the problem that I got, was the data not displayed completely in `DataGridView`.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dta As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dts As DataSet
    Dim excelpath As String

    Dim ExcelQuery As String = "Select * From [IOT_NOVA$B12:S257]"

    Try

        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please select Excel file to upload!", vbExclamation)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        excelpath = TextBox1.Text
        conn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelpath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';")
        dta = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(ExcelQuery, conn)

        DtSet = New DataTable
        dta.Fill(DtSet)


        DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet
        
        conn.Close()
        conn.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the table name when setting the DataSource of the DataGridview.

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
```

or

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables("IOT_NOVA")
```

Comment: Set or not the table name but the result is same. The problem was, the data displayed in datagridview but missing some data that with more than 1000 caracteres/digits.

Comment: Could anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: Is it possible to upload this Excel file to say Microsoft OneDrive (it's free) if the data is not sensitive data. I can then give it a try to see what the issue may be.

Comment: The data is sensitive. Could you please download it via google drive that i linked here.

Comment: If you supply a link to Google Drive I can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You may have (had) an issue with default column box sizes.
See this question:
[How to set max length of datagridview column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903087/how-to-set-max-length-of-datagridview-column)
Edit: found another issue - excel data driver is buggy.
Look far down in this thread:
[How do I create an Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file in C# without installing Microsoft Office?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/how-do-i-create-an-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-in-c-sharp-without-installing-mic?rq=1)

Comment: Hi, sorry for late. the default size of gridviewtextboxcolumn is 32767.