# DataGridView c# doesn't show long length string value

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I created many dynamically DataGridView in window form by using c# and gave them some values. One of my values is a string with about 30000 char(string length = 28447) my problem is that string don't display in cell. I tested with short length string and that was work but long length doesn't work.

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)Dgv.Rows[0].Clone();
row.Cells[0].Value = " Sequences" + (i + 1);
((DataGridViewTextBoxCell)row.Cells[1]).MaxInputLength = SequencesLenght * 3;  //Sequences length for my test is: 10000
row.Cells[1].Value = SequencesString[i];
Dgv.Rows.Add(row);
```

Thank you

Comment: [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903087/how-to-set-max-length-of-datagridview-column) might help you?

Comment: thank you and I tested that way before that doesn't work too.

Comment: ok try `((DataGridViewTextBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[yourColumn]).MaxInputLength = 32767`

Comment: my cell width become bigger but doesn't show any things.

Comment: add your code in a question which you have written to bind DataGridView.

Comment: I added my code

Comment: you might try to replace this string cell with the Button "Show information" and there in a new window show this long string in a TextBox or RichTextBox ... because DataGridView is not designed to show that big string to user

Comment: _doesn't work_ is not a helpful problem description!! - There is an upper limit (32k) of how many __pixels any__ control can display in either direction. 30k character will hit this with __every font__.