# Set cell input length to 4 digits(numeric only) and reject duplicate inputs C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView named "dgPins" in a Uer Interface. The columns are as shown below.

[image]

Now I'm looking to accomplish 2 tasks with this DataGridView.

1. To limit the input size for the cells under column "PIN" to 4 digit numeric only.

I know for **TextBox** there's a property **MaxLength** where you can set the input length. Is there a simpler way to do it for DGVs too? And how to set the value type to numeric? I found a rollback solution [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645458/make-a-specific-column-only-accept-numeric-value-in-datagridview-in-keypress-eve) But its not the most convenient answer for me.

2. How to make an event handler to reject duplicate inputs for the same column cells? What even should I use to program this?

Comment: To limit input size - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903087/how-to-set-max-length-of-datagridview-column

Comment: And to disallow duplicate values look at this event https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx